# json de apple 100 álbumes agregar un search

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, reactjs

tengo que crear una página en donde se muestren los [100 álbumes de apple](https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=100/json) ya los tengo mostrado, lo que necesito hacer es poner un buscador y que sea funcional, pero no encuentro la manera de poderlo hacer ya que me cuesta reactJS, este es mi código de como lo muestro

```
class ListRoute extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hits: [],
      isLoading: true,
      error: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetchHits().then(result => {
        this.setState({
          hits: result.feed.entry,
          isLoading: false })
        }).catch(err => {
          this.setState({
            error: true,
            isLoading: false });
        })
      }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    const { hits, isLoading, error } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="container">
          { error &&
            <div className="error">I'm sorry! Error occured :(</div>
          }

          { isLoading ? (
            <Loader />
          ) : (
            <List list={hits}/>
          )
          }
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListRoute;
```

ahi aun no he agregado el buscador pero pienso agregar un buscador de [ant.design](https://ant.design/components/input/) que este seria el codigo

```
import { Input } from 'antd';

const { Search } = Input;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Search
      placeholder="input search text"
      onSearch={value => console.log(value)}
      style={{ width: 200 }}
    />
  </div>,
  mountNode,
);
```

aun me cuesta reactJS, si me pudieran ayudar seria de mucha ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En base a lo que he entendido he creado este pequeño Pen con una posible solución a lo que buscas. Cualquier duda estoy al pendiente.

https://codepen.io/Ciensprog/pen/XWbGzEO

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.

Comment: @gbianchi Lo siento si no cumplo con tus espectativas en cuanto a la respuesta. El enlace no desaparecerá, el motivo de hacer un _pen_ es para evitar extender mucho, además de poder previsualizar el código.

En mi opinión, si tienes muchos años de experiencia programando como dice tu perfil, puedes aportar y no criticar la humilde ayuda que se le da a otros.

Debo añadir, que soy nuevo en la plataforma para ayudar a otros. Recomiendo que valores y puedas dar tips en vez de hacer comentarios negativos a otros, seamos aplicables en cuanto a nivel de experiencia, incluso respondiendo.

Comment: No son mis espectativas. Son las del sitio. El enlace es solo codigo sin ninguna explicacion. Se pide que las respuestas sean completas y esten explicadas. Desconocemos si el enlace caducara o no. Asi como esta, no parece una respuesta, si no solo un enlace, que otro usuario con el mismo problema tenga que presionar y luego adivinar porque soluciona el problema. Lee por favor [answer]

Comment: No te sientas criticado negativamente. Mi critica es constructiva y es para que mejores tu respuesta. Ten en cuenta que aca las respuestas no se borran y la idea del sitio es ayudar no solo a quien pregunta si no a quien venga despues con una duda similar.

Comment: Además que aquí puedes colocar todo ese código y convertirlo en snnipet para que se ejecute aquí, checa el [tour]

Comment: Y gracias por tu aporte. En este lugar se agradece votando positivamente y aceptando respuestas. Y ten en cuenta que aunque no parezca, aca las respuestas completas y bien fundamentadas (aunque sean largas) son mejor apreciadas que solo tirar un poco de codigo. Ojala sigas participando y entendiendo que no es una critica negativa, si no una forma de que aportes mas positivamente todavia.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por los enlaces. Pero sí pienso que podría haber formulado de otra manera su comentario, de todas maneras aplicaré y mejoraré mis respuestas, gracias :)

Comment: Si algo de mi comentario te parecio fuera de lugar, por favor aclaramelo asi puedo mejorarlo.